# user#create render = 'new' does not work generates no template errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Note: I am running Rails 3.1.0

In Lesson #8: Sign up

In the tutorial at time index ~25:53 - I am following the instructions to render the new page when the create action is called.

the 'create' action for users_controller is a follows:

```
    def create
      @user = User.new
      @title = "signup"
      render = "new"
    end
```

When trying to render - I still get the "Missing Template" error displayed in the tutorial even after following the screencast.  It suggests that I still require a template -> views/users/create

Any ideas? is this related to Rails 3.1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

```
render :new
```

`render` is a method. `render :new` is basically the same as `render(:new)`. When you do `render = "new"` you just assign the string `"new"` to a new local variable `render`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Wiping yolk off face now.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
render = "new"
```

With:

```
render "new"
```

It's a method requiring an argument.